# Не выводит сопряженные и найденные устройства Bluetooth

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Пытаюсь сделать приложение вот по этому туториалу(на английском):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A41hkHoYu4M
Ссылка на GitHub с кодом:
https://github.com/philipplackner/BluetoothChat/tree/Part1-Scanning

Вроде бы в самом коде ошибок нет (т.е. нет тех из-за который код вообще не запускается), приложение открываю на телефоне.
**Проблема:**
Должна выводится надпись "Paired Devices" и после нее сопряженные устройства.
Но по факту выводится только эта надпись.

В logcat выводит несколько красных строк, но я не понимаю что они значат и как это пофиксить:

```
channel 'd38840f com.example.blueteeth/com.example.blueteeth.presentation.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
   
IOP HAL: Received pkg_name = com.example.blueteeth pid = -1
   
activityStartTrigger: not whiteListedcom.example.blueteeth/com.example.blueteeth.presentation.MainActivity/1
   
activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.example.blueteeth/com.example.blueteeth.presentation.MainActivity/1
   
activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.example.blueteeth/com.example.blueteeth.presentation.MainActivity/1
    
IOP HAL: Received pkg_name = com.example.blueteeth pid = 29161
```

Comment: Многое зависит от версии Android устройств, на которых запускаете. Автор туториала как-то это проскочил и использует телефоны Android 12+, насколько я понял.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Спасибо! Это объясняет, почему у меня не работает. А можно это как-то пофиксить? Или этот код только для Android 12+ и ничего сделать нельзя?

Comment: Там только с разрешениями надо поколдовать. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions